# What's the difference between this Javascript request and Python request?

Tags: javascript, python

I wrote something in Python and am trying to figure out why the hell the seemingly equivalent code in JS isn't working.

Working Python -

Headers used:

```
    self.session = requests.Session()
    #Set headers
    self.headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
}
```

Code:

```
link = 'https://www.kith.com/cart'
        data = [
    ('updates'+'['+'888074764295'+']', '1'),
    ('updates'+'['+'888463982599'+']', '0'),
        ]
        click = self.session.post(link, headers= self.headers, data=data, verify = False)
```

Not working JS -

```
      const secondaryVar = `updates[888463982599]`;
      const desiredVariant = `updates[888074764295]`;

      const checkoutForm = {};

      checkoutForm[desiredVariant] = '1';
      checkoutForm[secondaryVar] = '0';

      //Post request to cart to update it with desired product
      request({
              url: 'https://www.kith.com/cart',
              followAllRedirects: true,
              method: 'post',
              formData: checkoutForm,                  
          headers : {
                'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
                'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
                'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
                'Connection':'keep-alive',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
            },


          },

          function(err, res, body) {
```

I've narrowed it down to this bit of code, but as far as I can tell there is no significant difference between the code in Python and the JS code. My guess is it has something to do with the session or headers...but again I don't know.

Thanks for any responses

Comment: What JavaScript framework are you using, and what is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

I think the Python might not respect [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), which would explain the difference. I don't know what JavaScript framework you are using, but using jQuery, the following works when executing this code from the kith.com website.

To avoid any issues with CORS, I removed the headers that are automatically set by the browser, and I change the url from `www.kith.com` to `kith.com`.

```
jQuery.ajax("https://kith.com/cart", settings={method:"post", headers : {
                'Accept':'application/json',
                'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
            }, data:{"desiredVariant":1,"secondaryVar":0}}).error(function(err){console.log("error"+ err)}).success(function(res){console.log(res)})
```

Comment: Thank you! If you have time, could you further explain why www.kith doesn't work while kith does? Thanks!

Comment: www is a type of subdomain. When performing requests in JavaScript, the domains have to be exactly the same, unless, the server has specified that the mismatch is ok. 
This is done for security reasons, and is known as the same origin policy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). The practice of configuring a server to get around this limitation is known as CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: Whenever you load a third party library, they have configured their CORS policy to allow this. When CORS has not been configured, you are restricted to only loading resources from the same domain.